# Using clang's objcopy with input file returns: "File format not recognized"

Tags: android, android-ndk, clang, cross-compiling, objcopy

I am using the following command `arm-linux-androideabi-objcopy --redefine-syms mysyms obj1.o obj2.o`.
The binary is from the clang3.3 toolchain, which I built using the `Android NDK`.

The mysyms file contains value pairs in the format of

```
boo boo_1
foo foo_1
#eof
```

It works perfectly when using the gcc toolchain, but with the `clang` toolchain i get "File format not recognized".
Is the file format different?

I am using OSX, but I tried on an Ubuntu VM to re-create the mysyms file, just to be sure that the line endings are not messed up.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After wasting more than a day, the solution was "simple".

I have downloaded the NDK Revision 9D, released March 2014, and `objcopy` works as it should!
I was using the Revision 9C.

You can find the revisions bundles [here](https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html#Revisions), and their changelogs as well.